# How do I continue a conversation after my token has expired?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to use a conversation reference to continue a conversation with a user within my node bot server. This conversation, I assume, is trying to be resumed after the last API token received has expired. When I try to call `continueConversation` which is defined in `botFrameworkAdapter.ts` in the botbuilder library (note, that this is not within a turn, so no message has been received from Teams since the API key has expired), with my service URL as https://smba.trafficmanager.net/uk/ which is what I have stored in my conversation reference, I get an unauthorized error.

After digging into the botbuilder library, I have narrowed it down to the `shouldSetToken` method within `microsoftAppCredentials.js`. It would seem the issue is that https://smba.trafficmanager.net/uk/ is not a trusted host name, and as a result the connector does not attempt to retrieve a new token for use.

I can verify that changing the `shouldSetToken` method to always return true solves my issue, but what is the correct approach to do this which does not involve altering the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get around this for now with `MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(serviceUrl)`. If there is a better approach it'd be great to hear it.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT thanks Bill, I assume it's fine to trust any serviceUrl I receive inside a turnContext, and that it's not possible to be spoofed with some malicious URL?

Comment: That's correct. The serviceUrl comes from our back-end service that powers bot conversations.

Comment: Hi @BrendanHart, could you please tell me what exactly you did? i facing the same issue